# For-loop saying - ERROR Member reference base type 'int [13]' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, error-handling

What is the problem with my for-loop? It is inside a helper function but the error "Member reference base type 'int [13]' is not a structure or union" is happening across my code. The 'int [13] changes to int[10] when I am using a 10 integer array, so I assume it is a problem there.  Here are two examples:

```
        int newisbn13[13];
        newisbn13[0] = 9;
        newisbn13[1] = 7;
        newisbn13[2] = 8;
        for (int p = 3; p < newisbn13.length() - 1; p++)
        {
            newisbn13[p] = isbn10[p-3];
        }
```

ERROR: Member reference base type 'int [13]' is not a structure or union

Also:

```
int calc_check_digit_13(int input[], int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        int tempnum = 0;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            tempnum = input[i];
        }
        else if (i % 2 == 1)
        {
            tempnum = input[i] * 3;
        }
        sum = tempnum + sum;
    }
etc. etc. etc.
}
```

ERROR: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union

What is causing this error throughout my code? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newisbn13` is an array and in contrast to other languages like C# or Java it does not know its size.

You need to use `sizeof(newisbn13)` instead.
Or since c++17 you can use `std::size(newisbn13)`.

**However** this will not work for `calc_check_digit_13`. Because `input` will decay to a pointer and neither `sizeof` nor `std::size` will work there. But probably the parameter `size` is what you want to use.

`for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

For your first block of code, you make a call to a non-existent member function of type `int`. In C++, `int` is a primitive type and has no member functions or member variables.

For the second block, you're calling the same function but on a pointer to an array of `int`s, so the type is `int *` and not `int[13]`, but its pretty much the exact same problem.

As churill pointed out, you can use `sizeof(int[])` or `std::size(int[])` to find the number of elements in the array. If you need a container for integers, I would recommend using `std::vector<int>` to manage your `int`s. This template class has tons of quality-of-life methods such as `size()` that can assist with what you might want to do.